# Slider Html/Css dont move

Tags: html, css

Hi im tryng to make a slider with html/css but i cant make tehe code works:
This the CSS code:

```
.content { height: 520px;width: 935px; overflow: hidden; 
 position: absolute;top: 50%; left:50%; transform: 
 translate(-50%,-25%);}

.navigation { position: absolute; bottom: 20px; left : 50%; 
          transform: translate(-50%); display: flex;}

.bar { width: 70px; height: 17px; border: 2px solid  white;
  margin: 6px; border-radius: 5px; cursor: pointer; 
  transition: 0.4s;}

.bar:hover { background-color: white;}

.slides{ display: flex; /*width: 100%;  height: 100%;*/ } 
.slide { width: 20%; transition: .6s; }   
.slide img { width: 100%; height: 100%;}
#slide1:checked ~.s1 { margin-left:0;  }
#slide2:checked ~.s1 { margin-left: -20%;}
```

I think i m making samething wrong in the slides class  in the commented part this is the HTML code :

```
 <div class="content">
    <div class="slides">
        <input type="radio" name="slide" id="slide1" 
 checked>
        <input type="radio" name="slide" id="slide2">
        <input type="radio" name="slide" id="slide3">
        <input type="radio" name="slide" id="slide4">
        
    </div>
   
    <div class="slide" s1>
        <img src="img/XU/Xu1a.jpg" alt="Robaleiro Xu">
    </div>
    <div class="slide" >
        <img src="img/XU/Xu2a.jpg" alt="Robaleiro Xu">    
    </div>
    <div class="slide" >
        <img src="img/XU/Xu3a.jpg" alt="Robaleiro Xu">  
    </div>
    <div class="slide" >
        <img src="img/XU/Xu5a.jpg" alt="Robaleiro Xu">  
    </div>

  <div class="navigation"> 
      <label  class="bar"  for="slide1"></label>
      <label  class="bar"  for="slide2"></label>
      <label  class="bar"  for="slide3"></label>
      <label  class="bar"  for="slide4"></label>
  </div>
```

I have revised these codes many times, in the youtube sample this code works fine but not for me, thanks by any orientation Alejandro

Comment: There is nothing with class s1. And even if there were, the slides are not siblings of the radio inputs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand how the "~" CSS-selector works.

([article](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.php) | [example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss3_gen_sibling))

It selects a neighbour in same parent element. So the "input tag" and ".slide tag" are should have a same parent.

Here is the working example:

```css
.carousel {
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
}

ul.slides {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
}

.slides * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

ul.slides input {
    display: none; 
}


.slide-container { 
    display: block; 
}

.slide-image {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}   

.slide-image img {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-controls {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 600px;
    color: #fff;
}

.carousel-controls label {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slide-image:hover + .carousel-controls label{
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.carousel-controls label:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-controls .prev-slide {
    width: 49%;
    text-align: left;
    left: 0;
}

.carousel-controls .next-slide {
    width: 49%;
    text-align: right;
    right: 0;
}

.carousel-dots {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel-dots .carousel-dot {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin: 10px;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .slide-image {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .carousel-controls label {
     display: block; 
}

input#img-1:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-4,
input#img-5:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-5,
input#img-6:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-6 {
    opacity: 1;
}


input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="carousel">
    <ul class="slides">
      <input type="radio" name="radio-buttons" id="img-1" checked />
      <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide-image">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Timisoara_-_Regional_Business_Centre.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-controls">
          <label for="img-3" class="prev-slide">
            <span>&lsaquo;</span>
          </label>
          <label for="img-2" class="next-slide">
            <span>&rsaquo;</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </li>
      <input type="radio" name="radio-buttons" id="img-2" />
      <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide-image">
          <img src="https://content.r9cdn.net/rimg/dimg/db/02/06b291e8-city-14912-171317ad83a.jpg?width=1750&height=1000&xhint=3040&yhint=2553&crop=true">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-controls">
          <label for="img-1" class="prev-slide">
            <span>&lsaquo;</span>
          </label>
          <label for="img-3" class="next-slide">
            <span>&rsaquo;</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </li>
      <input type="radio" name="radio-buttons" id="img-3" />
      <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide-image">
          <img src="https://speakzeasy.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/twa_blogpic_timisoara-4415.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-controls">
          <label for="img-2" class="prev-slide">
            <span>&lsaquo;</span>
          </label>
          <label for="img-1" class="next-slide">
            <span>&rsaquo;</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </li>
      <div class="carousel-dots">
        <label for="img-1" class="carousel-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
        <label for="img-2" class="carousel-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
        <label for="img-3" class="carousel-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<center>Code by Anca Spatariu. Username @ancaspatariu on Codepen</center>
```

*Example by @ancaspatariu user from Codepen website.*

Comment: Aside from giving a definition and some links for `~`, this answer is very unhelpful. Copying other people's code from elsewhere to add to *your* answer doesn't help the OP know where their mistakes are.

Comment: @InSync Othervise. The first part of my answer is the theory. Which Alejandro have to understand before using this unusual selector. And the second part is the working example which shows the right structure of the code. So there is everything Alejandro needs to solve this issue.